# Where is this username / password stored?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I basically have the folder structure like this: 
[image]

Is it safe to share the folder (Optimate) or will it compromise the push username/password I have stored for this repository?

Comment: Why do you want to share it? Why not just let other people clone from the bitbucket repository instead?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karisen Its a sad sad story :) It was a one time thing and the guy is not familiar with any vcs ... I did delete the .hg folder (from the files that I was passing on in usb) before giving it but just wanted to be sure that I wasn't being over careful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably does compromise it, since the repo-specific information is stored in the `.hg\hgrc` file.

You may want to enable and use the [keyring exstension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeyringExtension) though, which solves this issue by saving credentials outside of the repositories.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you've stored the username and password as part of the bitbucket repository path in `.hg/hgrc`'s `[paths]` section. Since you said you deleted the `.hg` directory in the version you're sharing, it won't be a problem, as the `hgrc` file is gone now.

However, for other situations you might want to put your username and password in an [`[auth]` section](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth) in your `mercurial.ini` (or global `hgrc`) instead of in each bitbucket path. Your `[paths]` section of some repository's `hgrc` would look like this:

```
[paths]
default = https://bitbucket.org/myusername/myreponame
```

While your global config would have this section, telling it to use the specified username and password with any bitbucket urls:

```
[auth]
bb.prefix = bitbucket.org
bb.username = myusername
bb.password = mypassword
bb.schemes = https
```

Be aware that the keyring extension suggested by Lucero is more secure, as it stores the password securely rather than in plaintext. *I purposely leave mine plaintext since it is work-related. If something should happen to me, somebody else should be able to take over as admin.*

Comment: Really nice information. Thanks +1 I will definitely try it out.